Do we need to show cart icon if I am already in the cart page?
After clicking on the cart icon user will navigate to the cart page which items they selected so, in the cart page Do we need to saw the cart icon? I mean users already in the cart if we add icons users get confused and they will going to tap on that icon again.

If your cart page is well-designed and the icon shows that it's active, they'll be reassured. If your page is poorly designed or the icon looks inactive, they'll click it again.

It is quite usual to keep the cart icon visible at all times, also when you are already on the cart page. Amazon is an example and you could say that it is safe to assume people are familiar with the concept. But, it will only work if the icon is part of an element that is always present, like the navigation top bar on amazon.com. Also if user tests show that people get confused by the icon when they are already on the cart page, it is good to do an a-b test with and without the icon. Because some people might get confused with the icon, and others might get confused by the inconsistency when the icon suddenly isn't there anymore.

Good answer. A good navigation also shows which page is active. This also applies to icon navigations, in this case the cart icon.

Users will prefer a consistent experience over a navigation bar that is constantly changing.
Whether you use icons, text, or pictures to navigate through your site, you will be presenting users with some form of navigation bar or menu. This serves dual purposes of allowing navigation and indicating the user's current location e.g.:

When only icons or pictures are used, these are often combined with a page title to make it clear what page the user is on.
This practice is guided by two usability heuristics, #1 Visibility of System Status and #6 Recognition rather than Recall. As long as it is clear that clicking the cart icon takes the user away from the page they were on, and several indicators make it clear they are now on the cart page (e.g. a useful title and clear product list) then your users will be comfortable that their action has succeeded.
There is no need to remove the current page icon/tab from the navigation area. Being internally consistent with how you display navigation options will help users learn where things are (Heuristic #4 Consistency and Standards). If your Cart page is clearly a Cart page, users won't be looking to the Cart button, and there's no harm in them clicking it again, so it's better to keep your navbar consistent than risk confusion by conditionally hiding options and risking user frustration.
There are countless examples of large retail companies doing the same (making the cart/bag/trolley icon visible even on the cart/bag/trolley page) - Etsy, Amazon, New Look, Wickes, I could go on. Consistency with other websites that users are likely to be familiar with is an important asset to a designer. If it ain't broke...
